# Internals of geometry combination in Direct2D - how does it work?

Tags: direct2d

When combining 2 path geometries in Direct2D, does it tessellate 1 or 2 of the geometries in order to calculate the combined one?

Say I have a figure composed of 2 arcs, creating a circle. I'm combining it with a rectangle that partially overlaps with the circle, using union.

Will D2D create a new geometry where the (remaining part of the) arcs are internally represented by a series of short lines, or will it be smart enough to shorten the arc?

What about beziers?

And is your answer based on knowledge of the code, or is there an official documentation, or method of checking this?